"X increased two times." — What can this mean?
my own sentence:
(1) X increased two times.
What meanings can (1) have?:
(1a) X that increased to two times is two X.
(1b) X that increased by two times is three X.
(1c) X increased twice.

(1c) means the same as (1) (only twice is more idiomatic than two times).

It could mean that it increased on two occasions, or that it doubled, or that it increased by 200%
The literal, and only correct interpretation is the first, that on two occasions, X increased.  But I'm sure that people would incorrectly say "two times" instead of "two-fold" or something else.
But you should not use this sentence because it has the potential to be misunderstood.
